# Get number from several scientific notations

Tags: java, double, number-formatting

I have several Strings that I need to get as Double using [**NumberFormat**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html).
The Strings can have several formats, like this:

```
"0"           // case 1
"0.00003"     // case 2
"5e-76"       // case 3
"2E-10"       // case 4
```

I use the following code to get the double values:

```
    NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
    String val = "2e-7";
    try {
        Number number = numberFormat.parse(val);
        System.out.println("number: " + number.doubleValue());
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        System.out.println("error: " + ex);
    }
```

This works fine except for the case 3 (running above code will print "number: 2.0")

**Requirements:**

I know that `Double.valueOf(val)` would work fine here, however I'm looking for a solution using NumberFormat only.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case 3 fails because "e" is in lower case. We could create a subclass of NumberFormat which upper-cases the string before parsing it.

```
public final class CaseInsensitiveNumberFormat extends NumberFormat {
    private final NumberFormat mParent;
    private final Locale mLocale;

    public CaseInsensitiveNumberFormat(Locale locale) {
        mParent = NumberFormat.getInstance(locale);
        mLocale = locale;
    }

    @Override
    public final Number parse(String s, ParsePosition pos) {
        return mParent.parse(s.toUpperCase(mLocale), pos);   // <------
    }

    @Override
    public final StringBuffer format(double number, StringBuffer appendTo, FieldPosition pos) {
        return mParent.format(number, appendTo, pos);
    }

    @Override
    public final StringBuffer format(long number, StringBuffer appendTo, FieldPosition pos) {
        return mParent.format(number, appendTo, pos);
    }
}
```

```
NumberFormat fmt = new CaseInsensitiveNumberFormat(Locale.US);

System.out.println(fmt.parse("0"));       // 0
System.out.println(fmt.parse("0.00003")); // 3.0E-5
System.out.println(fmt.parse("5e-76"));   // 5.0E-76
System.out.println(fmt.parse("2E-10"));   // 2.0E-10
```